# Testing "if" against multiple segments

Tags: templating

Got myself into a seemingly simple dead-end block with twig syntax. I need to test against multiple items:

```
{% set segment1 = craft.request.firstSegment %}
{% if segment1 == 'one OR two OR three' %}
DO SOMETHING
{% endif %}
```

What's going wrong with this bit 'one OR two OR three'? brackets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've just got quotes wrapped around a simple string. Try something like this instead...

```
{% if segment1 in ['one','two','three'] %}
```

That will check to see if your `segment1` value is in the array of possible matches.

Comment: Super thanks. I got caught out by the "in"!